# restful angularjs $http get return null

Tags: angularjs, rest

I'm trying AngularJS for the first time. I'm getting as imple user JSON data from a http-get request, but the object is returned null. I tested my service using chrome and I get this result:

[{"id":1,"email":"walid@gmail.com","name":"walid"}]

Below my js file:

```
var app = angular.module("userApp", []);
app.controller("userController", function($scope, $http) {
$scope.user = null;
$scope.name = null;

$scope.getUser = function() {
    $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : '/all',
    }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.user = json.stringify(data);
    }).error(function(data) {
        alert('Fail: user is  '+data);

        });
    }
});
```

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>SIM Card</title>
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/simcard.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/simcard2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/json2.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="userApp" ng-controller="userController">

<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="panel panel-info spacer">
        <div class="panel-heading">User Management</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form action="">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>ID</label> <input type="text" ng-model="email">
                    <button ng-click="getUser()" type="submit">Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="panel panel-info spacer">
        <div class="panel-heading">Result</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name: </label>
                <label>{{user.name}}</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can send the whole maven project in case needed. Thank you for your help.

Regards,
Walid

Comment: What is the URL of the REST service?

Comment: Where do you get the REST service?! Is it local or it's online!?

Comment: yes it is local: http://localhost:8080/all

Comment: "I can send the whole maven project in case needed" I don't think that would be needed. Instead, you should try to create a [mcve] - what can you remove from your code and still reproduce the problem?

Comment: @WalidRoamsmart Check my answer and let me know if you needed any more information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your config of the request:
http://plnkr.co/edit/qEkpUAXQQZmO9iUAZ2aX?p=preview

It doesn't know what type of data you expect in response.

Your http request should look like this:

```
 $http.get("test.json").success(function(data) {
    $scope.user = data[0];
}).error(function(data) {
    alert('Fail: user is 2 '+data);
});
```

**Update**:

Just noticed something in yout HTML - you have there a form with action empty. This is the cause of the request being canceled.
in angularjs to have a form, it is enought to add to a div `ng-form="myForm"` and the input can be just simple button, not submit and it is going to work fine.

Comment: still gettings user is null:

Comment: @WalidRoamsmart can you provide a snapshot of your request/response visibile in dev tools?

Comment: just added the image file

Comment: Hello Diana, I got the same result

Comment: @WalidRoamsmart you can post here the links, or edit your initial question to add them instead of posting as answers - this is a bad practice. Can you send me the maven project so I can see the entire source code?

Comment: @WalidRoamsmart just updated my answer. Check the update.

Comment: Sorry diana, this is the first question I'm posting here, I will try to follow the best practice... Can you share your email address so that I can send you the project? my email is w.benchamekh@roam-smart.com

Comment: @WalidRoamsmart Just check first my update in the answer if this doesn't fix your issue, then I will need the code (you don't need my email, just zip it and upload to any sharing website and provide here the link).

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this:

```
var app = angular.module("userApp", []);
app.controller("userController", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getUser = function() {
       return $http.get('/all').then(
            function successCallback(response) {
                // you can log response here to see what it is
                // or you can simply check network in your browser DevTools
                $scope.users = response;
            },
            function errorCallback(response) {
                alert('There was error retrieving users List');
            }
        );
    };
});
```

once that is done based on your response which is an array you can repeat it in your view. ngRepeat is also watching your model update so every time you update `$scope.users` it will update itself.

So you can simply use this in your **view**:

```
<div ng-app="userApp" ng-controller="userController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="user in users">
           <span> {{user.id}} {{user.name}} {{user.email}} </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The benefit of using `$http.get(...).then()` is that you can you can use promise chain with ease to build other services on top of this. In your case you have to make sure that you check your response.

**// Update :**

Here's a Bin that you can see the code above in action: https://jsbin.com/luguzu/1/edit

Just in output hit **Run with js** and click ***Get Users***.

Comment: I've used https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ for getting user information in the bin.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is the image of my network console...  [image]

Comment: Looks like your request is not even sent. Also, you should send the request to : $http.get("all").success(function(data) {
    $scope.user = data[0];
}).error(function(data) {
    alert('Fail: user is 2 '+data);
});
In the link I showed you, it just does a request to test.json which is a file. In your case, is link "all". Try that and see what you get.

Comment: Great. Then make sure you mark the answer as resolved for other people who will have the same issue.